# Trouble using sprintf()

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I am using `sprintf` to convert an int to a string. I am then passing the string to a function "enqueue" . This function accepts the string and inserts it into a FIFO linked list. The problem is, when I call `enqueue()` with explicit strings it works perfectly, but when I call it with the `sprintf` string buffer, it somehow overwrites the elements that were already present in the queue.

```
typedef struct
{
    char *movie;
    char *pkt;
} packet ;

struct node
{
    packet page;
    struct node *next;
} *front= NULL, *rear=NULL;

void display_fifo(){
    struct node *t;
    t=front;
    while ((front==NULL)|| (rear==NULL))
            {
            printf("\nempty fifo\n");
            return ;
            }
    while (t!=NULL)
    {
            printf("->%s\t %s\n", t->page.movie, t->page.pkt);
            t= t-> next;
    }
}
void enqueue(char * movie, char *pkt)
{
    packet new;
    new.movie= movie;
    new.pkt=pkt;
    struct node *p;
    p= (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->page= new;
    p->next= NULL;

    if (rear== NULL|| front ==NULL)
            front=p;
    else
            rear->next=p;
    rear=p;
}
void main(){
    char buff[10];
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<=5;i++){
            sprintf(buff, "%d", i);
            enqueue("1", buff);
            printf("***\n");
            display_fifo();
    }

}
```

The output I get for the code written above:

```
***
->1    1
***
->1    2
->1    2
***
->1    3
->1    3
->1    3
***
->1    4
->1    4
->1    4
->1    4
***
->1    5
->1    5
->1    5
->1    5
->1    5
```

Is there an alternative to `sprintf` that returns a char pointer that I should be using or is my `enqueue()` a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you use a char* buff and in your enqueue function you copy the pointer !

```
new.pkt=pkt;
```

this is wrong and every time you change the buff , all other node values will change , because all of them reference to same buffer.
you must change this line!

```
new.pkt = pkt;
```

with

```
new.pkt = malloc(strlen(pkt));
strcpy(new.pkt,pkt);
```

Comment: It's probably a better idea to have the `enqueue` function allocate the memory, yes. I would recommend using `strdup` instead of `malloc`+`strcpy` though (would it be only because it is a single call).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you reuse the same buffer all the time. You always get the same pointer by referencing `buff`, so you keep overwriting your string.

You can either use `malloc` to create a new buffer, or the non-standard GNU extension [`asprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) (available on Linux systems and Mac OS X at least, but certainly not Windows) that allocates the necessary memory. In both cases, you need to `free` the pointer when you're done with it.

Also, you should avoid using `sprintf` and use `snprintf` instead to protect your programs from buffer overflows. (I would advise against using `sprintf` at all if you don't know the size of your buffer.)

A call to `asprintf` looks like this:

```c
char* buffer;
asprintf(&buffer, "%d", i);
// do stuff with buffer; it now points to a number string
free(buffer);
```

`malloc`+`snprintf` is slightly more complex as you need to determine the size of the buffer to allocate:

```c
char* buffer;
int i, allocSize;
// log10(number) is the digit count in `number` minus one, so
// we add two to account for the null terminator
allocSize = log10(i) + 2;
buffer = malloc(allocSize * sizeof *buffer);
snprintf(buffer, allocSize, "%d", i);
// do stuff with buffer; it now points to a number string
free(buffer);
```

Comment: I would also suggest steering away from argument names like "new" which may create conflict with C++ key words. Just in case you decide to reuse the code in another C++ project later.

Answer (score 1):

Your `packet` is storing a pointer to the characters, not the characters themselves. And the pointer is always pointing to `buff`.

Either malloc some memory to hold the characters, or add make `pkt` be an array of `char`.